# How to get element/name of the iFrame (with same-origin disallowed by sandbox attribute) sending postMessage to parent

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox, same-origin-policy

Right now I have 3 iframes with names "iframe1", "iframe2" and "iframe3", all of them are same-origin like parent, I have control over both sides.
One of the iframes sends some postMessage to the parent.

**I want to achieve 2 things:**

1. Be able to identify inside parent the element (or name) of iframe which sends the postMessage.
2. But also prevent iframes from accessing parent's Window object.

I've used HTML5 sandbox attribute on all iframes, allowing everything but "allow-same-origin". I successfully wasn't able to access parent's object from iframes anymore, the thing is that i couldn't identify the element of the iframe sending postMessage anymore. That's because "e.source.name" (e is the event object returned by recieved message) triggers SecurityError of Sandbox access violation and lack of the "allow-same-origin" flag.

I tested other event object's properties:

e.origin - returns null.

e.source - returns Window object, but its properties and methods can't be accessed

**The question is:**
How can I get to know name of the iFrame element sending postMessage to parent and prevent iFrames from being able to access parent's object? Maybe there's other workaround without using sandbox on iframes?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any control over what the iframe sends?